# Select correct username from database PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a PM system and I have everything down, besides figuring out how the correct person will get the correct message.

There's this code:

```
  $query = "SELECT to, from, rank, gender, picture, title, post FROM kaoscraft_posts WHERE to = 'username' ORDER BY msg_id DESC";
```

I have submitting it to the database down, and getting it, but I need to make sure the correct person gets the message.

Comment: @ElefantPhace I'm sorry... what more should I add in? Do I need to add the form... info on how I cna make this question better would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What your actual problem is would help. When you say "I need to make sure the correct person gets the message." doesn't really mean anything to us

Comment: @ElefantPhace  I see, okay. My problem is that I need to know what I should do to make the message viewable by the correct person... like, I would be able to use the user ID in other things, but the user ID isn't stored in this database. Could I use a session of username to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to` and `from` are reserved words which must be wrapped using backticks `` ` ``

**http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

```
$query = "SELECT `to`, `from`, rank, gender, picture, title, post FROM kaoscraft_posts WHERE `to` = 'username' ORDER BY msg_id DESC";
```

Yet, this

```
WHERE `to` = 'username'
```

may need to be

```
WHERE `to` = '$username'
```

which I suspect could be coming from a POST variable, which is not shown in your question.

If a part of your code resembles something to the effect of:

```
$username=$_POST['username'];
```

then use the following in its place:

```
WHERE `to` = '$username'
```

Answer (score 0):

When inserting to the database just provide the "From" or "To" field to your database. for example

$query = "SELECT * from MESSAGES where to = '$username'"

Comment: Your answer helped me, but the one above solved it. Thank you

Comment: That's okay. I'm happy my idea helped someone. :) The one with the most accurate answer will definitely get the points. :D